# Javascript count values on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have some data and one of the fields is called tags and in will sometimes contain an array of values.

What I need to do is to count those values and get them into separate variables.

Here is the data:

```
myObject = [

{
"object": [
        {
            "id": "8062",
            "name": "name 1"
            "tags": ['tag1','tag2'],
            "desc": "desc 1",
        },
        {
            "id": "8061",
            "name": "name 2"
            "tags": ['tag 2', 'tag 3'],
            "desc": "desc 2"

        },
        {
        "id": "8060",
        "name": "name 3"
        "tags": ['tag 2', 'tag 3'],
        "desc": "desc 3"

        }
    ]
}

];
```

And this is what I need to end up with:

```
tag1_count = 1;
tag2_count = 3;
tag3_count = 2;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Iterate through the array and cont. When you get a specific problem - come back with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` like this and return object.

```js
var myObject = [{
  "object": [{
    "id": "8062",
    "name": "name 1",
    "tags": ['tag1', 'tag2'],
    "desc": "desc 1",
  }, {
    "id": "8061",
    "name": "name 2",
    "tags": ['tag 2', 'tag 3'],
    "desc": "desc 2"
  }, {
    "id": "8060",
    "name": "name 3",
    "tags": ['tag 2', 'tag 3'],
    "desc": "desc 3"

  }]
}];

var result = myObject[0].object.reduce(function(r, e) {
  e.tags.forEach(function(t) {
    var key = t.replace(/ /g, '') + '_count'
    r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + 1;
  })
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
myObject = [{
  "object": [{
    "id": "8062",
    "name": "name 1",
    "tags": ['tag1', 'tag2'],
    "desc": "desc 1"
  }, {
    "id": "8061",
    "name": "name 2",
    "tags": ['tag2', 'tag3'],
    "desc": "desc 2"

  }, {
    "id": "8060",
    "name": "name 3",
    "tags": ['tag2', 'tag3'],
    "desc": "desc 3"

  }]
}];

var map = {};

myObject[0].object.forEach(function(object) {
  object.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    if(map[tag] === undefined){
      map[tag] = 1;  
    }else{
      map[tag] = map[tag] + 1; 
    }
  });
});

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply iterate through the array using `for-of` loop, get each length of `tags` property and store each desired value to different variables.

```
var i = 1;
for (obj of myObject[0].object) {
    window["tag" + i + "_count"] = obj.tags.length; // e.g. tag1_count = 2, tag2_count = 3, etc...
    i++;
}
```